# Return std::nullopt as a non-constant reference

Tags: c++, std, c++17, stdoptional

Form academic point of view, if I wanted to return std::nullopt as a non-constant reference. How will I be doing the same.

Little background, today when I was working on a code returning an std::optional> reference but I forgot to make the return constant and I got the error.

> ```
> Error (active)    E0434   a reference of type "std::optional<std::vector<std::any, std::allocator<std::any>>> &" (not const-qualified) cannot be initialized with a value of type "const std::nullopt_t"
> Socket.IO   D:\Hardware\Windows\Visual Studio\Socket.IO\Socket.IO\main.cpp  46  
>
> Error C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'const std::nullopt_t' to 'std::optional<std::vector<std::any,std::allocator<_Ty>>> &'
> Socket.IO   d:\hardware\windows\visual studio\socket.io\socket.io\main.cpp  46
> ```

Just wanted to know if someone wanted to return an non-constant reference using std::optional how would he be doing so.

Platform Used : Windows 10 Pro x64

Development Environment : Visual Studios 15.9.9

```
std::vector<int>> a;
std::optional<std::vector<int>>& test(int b)
{
    a.clear();
    a.push_back(b);
    if(b)
         return a;
    else
         return std::nullopt;
}
```

Comment: Returning a reference to a temporary value is a bad idea anyway, i.e. it would be undefined behaviour to access it.

Comment: @PaulR, I am aware of that. I was returning a global variable which was only visible inside a file.

Comment: No you aren't. both paths are returning a temporary

Comment: Since you return a reference to `std::optional<std::vector<int>>`, not `std::vector<int>` (which is the type of `a`) the `return a;` tries to return a reference to a temporary (constructed from `a`).

Comment: You can create a `static std::optional<std::vector<int>> dummy;` within your function and then `return dummy;`. However, since you return by reference, anyone could change the value of `dummy` to an arbitrary value. I do not recommend doing so, but that's how you could do it. Returning a const-reference would be a little bit more safe.

Comment: It would be equally wrong to return a const reference.

Comment: @molbdnilo Why would it be wrong to return a function local static variable by const reference?

Comment: @pschill There is no such thing in this code.

Comment: @DarkSorrow May I boldly suggest you practice standard C++ [value based semantics](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/value-vs-ref-semantics)? I would not say "always" but "as much as you can". Ah, yes, using `auto` would also help a lot.

Comment: @molbdnilo There is. It is the first sentence of my comment.

Comment: @pschill I was not responding to your comment, and returning a const reference to the other temporary would still be wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::nullopt` is not a `std::optional<std::vector<int>>` (nor is `a`), it is an object that has an implicit conversion to that type.

You can't bind a non-const reference to a temporary, such as the result of a conversion.

I'm not sure you should be returning a reference to an optional, but rather an "optional reference". `std::optional<std::vector<int> &>` is not a valid type, but both `std::vector<int> *` and `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<std::vector<int>>>` are, and they model "optional reference".

Comment: Well, here's the to an edit coming in a second before I post on an answer